# Synchronize threads from different processes using semaphore

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, semaphore

I have problem  with semaphore in C. I have a parent process and a child process. Both can create 3 threads and I must display the beginning and the end of threads and I must impose the next condition: the thread with id 1  from parent process must display its beginning after the thread with id 2 from child process display its end. I use a semaphore, but when I do wait, the thread with id 1 from parent process it doesn't remain stuck at semaphore and continue to display the beginning. I can't use function usleep() or sleep().

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>


sem_t* s=NULL;

void* function1(void* arg)
{
   int* nrth=(int*) arg;
   sem_t   * s=NULL;

   s=sem_open("mysemaphore",O_EXCL);
   if(s==NULL)
       perror("Error");

   if(*nrth==1)
       sem_wait(s);


   printf("Begin P1, thread %d\n",*nrth);
   printf("End P1, thread %d\n",*nrth);


   sem_close(s);
   return 0;

}



void* function2(void* arg)
{
    int* nrth=(int*) arg;

    sem_t   * s=NULL;
    s=sem_open("mysemaphore",O_EXCL);
    if(s==NULL)
        perror("Error");

    printf("Begin P2, thread %d\n",*nrth);
    printf("End P2, thread %d\n",*nrth);

    if(*nrth==2)
       sem_post(s);

    sem_close(s);

    return 0;
}


int main()
{
   sem_unlink("mysemaphore");
   s=sem_open("mysemaphore",O_CREAT,0644,1);
   if(s==NULL)
      perror("ERROR!");


   pthread_t threads[4];
   int index[4];
   pthread_t threads2[4];
   int index2[4];

   if(fork()==0)
   {

      printf("Begin: process 2 \n");

       for(int i=1; i<=3; i++)
       {
          index2[i]=i;
          pthread_create(&threads2[i],NULL,function2,&index2[i]);
       }
       for(int i=1; i<=3; i++)
       {
          pthread_join(threads2[i],NULL);
       }
       printf("End: process 2 \n");
   }
   else
   {
       printf("Begin: process 1\n");

       for(int i=1; i<=3; i++)
       {
          index[i]=i;
          pthread_create(&threads[i],NULL,function1,&index[i]);
       }

       for(int i=1; i<=3; i++)
       {
           pthread_join(threads[i],NULL);
       }
       printf("End: process 2 \n");

       wait(NULL);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are destroying your semaphore in both `function1()` and `function2()` when you call `sem_destroy()`, after which the behavior of that semaphore is undefined.  That may be your biggest problem.

You should be using `sem_close()` instead after you are finished using the semaphore that you obtained from `sem_open()`.

Comment: I change it to sem_close(), but the same thing happens.

Comment: Now your next problem is that the first thread running `function1()` will not block when it calls `sem_wait()` because when you create the semaphore, it has an initial value of 1.  `sem_wait()` will decrement to 0 and continue immediately. If you create your semaphore with an initial value of 0, the first call to `sem_wait()` will block until one of them `sem_post()` methods fire in `function2()`.